# Multiple Images upload in android asynchronously using phonegap

Tags: android, android-asynctask, phonegap-plugins, asyncfileupload

I have an issue with multiple images upload to php server. The code given below works fine for android 2.x versions, but the same code doesn't work for android 4.x and above. I have googled and found out that the data posting has to be done asynchronously by AsyncTask. But I have no clue about how it has to be done via phonegap(calling of async task).

Here I have my code :

```
package com.mymedlinks.hybrid;

import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class SamplePlugin extends Plugin{
    public String ACTION_POST_DATA="post_data";

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String arg0, JSONArray arg1, String arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PluginResult pluginRes;
        if(ACTION_POST_DATA.equals(arg0)){
            try {
                pluginResult = imgsUpload(args.getString(0),
                        args.getString(1), args.getString(2));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else{
            pluginRes = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);;
        }
        return pluginRes;
    }

    private PluginResult imgsUpload(String date,String time,
             String fileNames) {
             PluginResult pluginResult=null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        byte[] imgData = null;
        String urlString = "https://www.mysampledata.com/upload_imgs.php";

                //opening of http connection
                try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=---------------------------1177141514664");
            String msg = "";
            StringBuffer buffr = new StringBuffer(msg);

            buffr.append("-----------------------------1177141514664");
            buffr.append(CrLf);
            buffr.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"date\";"
                    + CrLf);
            buffr.append(CrLf);
            buffr.append(date + CrLf);

            buffr.append("-----------------------------1177141514664");
            buffr.append(CrLf);
            buffr.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"time\";"
                    + CrLf);
            buffr.append(CrLf);
            buffr.append(time + CrLf);

            buffr.append("-----------------------------1177141514664");
            buffr.append(CrLf);
            buffr.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"MAX_FILE_SIZE\";"
                    + CrLf);
            buffr.append(CrLf);
            buffr.append("100000000072000" + CrLf);

            buffr.append("-----------------------------1177141514664");
            buffr.append(CrLf);
            buffr.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"method\";"
                    + CrLf);
            buffr.append(CrLf);
            buffr.append("upload.snapshots" + CrLf);

            String msg1 = "";
            StringBuffer buffr1 = new StringBuffer(msg1);
            List<byte[]> byetsInfo = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
            ArrayList<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(new String(fileNames));
                JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("snapshot_images");
                String drPath = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    String img = jArray.getString(i);
                    Log.e("sample app", " imageName " + img);

                    File f = new File(drPath + "/sample_app_images/" + img);
                    Uri ur = Uri.fromFile(f);
                    filenames.add(img);
                    Bitmap bmp;
                    try {
                        bmp = Media.getBitmap(this.cordova.getActivity()
                                .getContentResolver(), ur);
                        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos);

                        imgData = baos.toByteArray();
                        Log.e("sample app", " img data size " + imgData.length);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    byetsInfo.add(imgData);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            String msg3 = "";
            StringBuffer buffr3 = new StringBuffer(msg3);
            buffr3.append(CrLf);
            buffr3.append("-----------------------------4664151417711--");
            buffr3.append(CrLf);

            conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < byetsInfo.size(); i++) {
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                buffr1.delete(0, buffr1.length());
                buffr1.append("-----------------------------1177141514664");
                buffr1.append(CrLf);
                buffr1.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"snapshotUpload[]\"; filename=\""
                        + filenames.get(i) + "\"" + CrLf);
                buffr1.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + CrLf);
                buffr1.append(CrLf);

                dos.write(buffr.toString().getBytes());
                dos.write(buffr1.toString().getBytes());

                int index = 0;
                int size = 1024;
                do {

                    if ((index + size) < byetsInfo.get(i).length) {
                        size = byetsInfo.get(i).length - index;
                    }
                    dos.write(byetsInfo.get(i), index, size);
                    index += size;
                } while (index < byetsInfo.get(i).length);
                Log.e("file upload ", " written: " + index);

                dos.write(buffr3.toString().getBytes());

            }

            Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
            Log.e("activity upload demo ",
                    " in file upload " + conn.getResponseMessage());
            dos.flush();

        } catch (Exception ec) {
            ec.printStackTrace();
        }

           String s=null;
        // Read the response
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            char buff = 512;
            int len;
            byte[] data = new byte[buff];
            do {
                len = inStream.read(data);
                if (len > 0) {
                    System.out.println(new String(data, 0, len));
                    s+=new String(data, 0, len);
                    Log.e("sample app", "  "
                            + new String(data, 0, len));
                }
            } while (len > 0);
            Log.e("file upload ", " DONE ");

            dos.close();
            inStream.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

                try {
            if(conn.getResponseMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("OK") && s!=null){
                pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, s);
            } else {
                pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,
                        false);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return pluginResult;

    }

}
```

The data in the code that is filenames, date and time I get from js code which will be sent to the above class. Can anyone please provide me with an example about how the Async Task can be called via Phonegap (i.e., calling it in the imgsUpload())

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution for this and it's here  [Multiple Image Upload using AsyncTask in Android using Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796306/multiple-image-upload-using-asynctask-in-android-using-phonegap)

Either ways the code seems to work fine on all devices once the following line of code is removed

```
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code I am using for upload image to the server you can use with AsynTask.

```
//this method takes Inputs (Image name and Image file path where it stored)
//and after upload it returns json response

public String pushImage(String filepath,String imageName){


    Log.v(TAG, "path is:"+filepath);
    Log.v(TAG, "image name is:"+imageName);
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    DataInputStream inStream = null;

    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;


    String reponse_data=null;
    try{
        //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST      

        //set request properties
        // here baseURL is url for uploading image
        URL url = new URL(baseURL);        
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();        
        conn.setDoInput(true);       
        conn.setDoOutput(true);       
        conn.setUseCaches(false);       
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);



        //add request body        

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd+twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);        

        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded\";filename=\"" + imageName + "\"" + lineEnd);     

        dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n");

        //now add image data


        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath) );

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0){
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }     

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }


    //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
        if(conn !=null){
            inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
        }

        String str=null;

        if(inStream !=null){
             while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null){
                 Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
                 reponse_data=str;
             }


             inStream.close();
        }


    }
    catch (IOException ioex){
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
   return reponse_data;
}
```

you can download **commons-io-2.4.jar** from [this](http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi) link

Comment: its the same code which I wrote... My code is also working. My question is how to call async task, since its not working in 4.x versions @RDC