# Uploading Multiple Images with Phonegap

Tags: ios, image, cordova, iphone-web-app

I'm looking for some advice on the best practice for uploading multiple images to a server via Phonegap.  Currently I have an app that will open the camera, take a picture, and then upload that as base64 data along with other form data via POST.  I would like to allow uploading of 3 images with the form data. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738194/multiple-images-upload-in-android-asynchronously-using-phonegap  Same question with answer

Comment: I'm not looking to do it with android.  Just javascript for a web app wrapped in Phonegap for iOS